# Can't install ROS on Ubuntu 16.04 due to Unmet Dependency Problem

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I am having the good old unmet dependency cancer for hours and I've asked about this in ROSAnswers, where I was told that it is an Ubuntu problem hence my question here.

When I try to run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-kinetic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-kinetic-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-kinetic-perception but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-kinetic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-kinetic-urdf-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So, obviously, I won't sit and try them one by one as this is not really an intelligent way of solving this.

So, I rather did:

```
sudo aptitude install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

to see the big picture, and I got the following output:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Reading extended state information...
Initializing package states...
Building tag database...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
== [tons of stuff which I cannot copy due to  character limit]==
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

       Keep the following packages at their current version:         
1)       libvtk6-dev [Not Installed]                                 
2)       libvtk6-java [Not Installed]                                
3)       libvtk6-qt-dev [Not Installed]                              
4)       libvtk6.2 [Not Installed]                                   
5)       libvtk6.2-qt [Not Installed]                                
6)       python-vtk6 [Not Installed]                                 
7)       ros-kinetic-actionlib [Not Installed]                       
8)       ros-kinetic-actionlib-msgs [Not Installed]                  
9)       ros-kinetic-actionlib-tutorials [Not Installed]             
10)      ros-kinetic-bond [Not Installed]                            
11)      ros-kinetic-bond-core [Not Installed]                       
12)      ros-kinetic-bondcpp [Not Installed]                         
13)      ros-kinetic-bondpy [Not Installed]                          
14)      ros-kinetic-camera-calibration [Not Installed]              
15)      ros-kinetic-camera-calibration-parsers [Not Installed]      
16)      ros-kinetic-camera-info-manager [Not Installed]             
17)      ros-kinetic-catkin [Not Installed]                          
18)      ros-kinetic-class-loader [Not Installed]                    
19)      ros-kinetic-collada-parser [Not Installed]                  
20)      ros-kinetic-collada-urdf [Not Installed]                    
21)      ros-kinetic-common-msgs [Not Installed]                     
22)      ros-kinetic-common-tutorials [Not Installed]                
23)      ros-kinetic-compressed-depth-image-transport [Not Installed]
24)      ros-kinetic-compressed-image-transport [Not Installed]      
25)      ros-kinetic-control-msgs [Not Installed]                    
26)      ros-kinetic-cpp-common [Not Installed]                      
27)      ros-kinetic-cv-bridge [Not Installed]                       
28)      ros-kinetic-depth-image-proc [Not Installed]                
29)      ros-kinetic-desktop [Not Installed]                         
30)      ros-kinetic-desktop-full [Not Installed]                    
31)      ros-kinetic-diagnostic-aggregator [Not Installed]           
32)      ros-kinetic-diagnostic-analysis [Not Installed]             
33)      ros-kinetic-diagnostic-common-diagnostics [Not Installed]   
34)      ros-kinetic-diagnostic-msgs [Not Installed]                 
35)      ros-kinetic-diagnostic-updater [Not Installed]              
36)      ros-kinetic-diagnostics [Not Installed]                     
37)      ros-kinetic-dynamic-reconfigure [Not Installed]             
38)      ros-kinetic-eigen-conversions [Not Installed]               
39)      ros-kinetic-eigen-stl-containers [Not Installed]            
40)      ros-kinetic-executive-smach [Not Installed]                 
41)      ros-kinetic-filters [Not Installed]                         
42)      ros-kinetic-gazebo-dev [Not Installed]                      
43)      ros-kinetic-gazebo-msgs [Not Installed]                     
44)      ros-kinetic-gazebo-plugins [Not Installed]                  
45)      ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros [Not Installed]                      
46)      ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-pkgs [Not Installed]                 
47)      ros-kinetic-gencpp [Not Installed]                          
48)      ros-kinetic-geneus [Not Installed]                          
49)      ros-kinetic-genlisp [Not Installed]                         
50)      ros-kinetic-genmsg [Not Installed]                          
51)      ros-kinetic-gennodejs [Not Installed]                       
52)      ros-kinetic-genpy [Not Installed]                           
53)      ros-kinetic-geometric-shapes [Not Installed]                
54)      ros-kinetic-geometry [Not Installed]                        
55)      ros-kinetic-geometry-msgs [Not Installed]                   
56)      ros-kinetic-geometry-tutorials [Not Installed]              
57)      ros-kinetic-gl-dependency [Not Installed]                   
58)      ros-kinetic-image-common [Not Installed]                    
59)      ros-kinetic-image-geometry [Not Installed]                  
60)      ros-kinetic-image-pipeline [Not Installed]                  
61)      ros-kinetic-image-proc [Not Installed]                      
62)      ros-kinetic-image-publisher [Not Installed]                 
63)      ros-kinetic-image-rotate [Not Installed]                    
64)      ros-kinetic-image-transport [Not Installed]                 
65)      ros-kinetic-image-transport-plugins [Not Installed]         
66)      ros-kinetic-image-view [Not Installed]                      
67)      ros-kinetic-interactive-marker-tutorials [Not Installed]    
68)      ros-kinetic-interactive-markers [Not Installed]             
69)      ros-kinetic-joint-state-publisher [Not Installed]           
70)      ros-kinetic-kdl-conversions [Not Installed]                 
71)      ros-kinetic-kdl-parser [Not Installed]                      
72)      ros-kinetic-laser-assembler [Not Installed]                 
73)      ros-kinetic-laser-filters [Not Installed]                   
74)      ros-kinetic-laser-geometry [Not Installed]                  
75)      ros-kinetic-laser-pipeline [Not Installed]                  
76)      ros-kinetic-librviz-tutorial [Not Installed]                
77)      ros-kinetic-map-msgs [Not Installed]                        
78)      ros-kinetic-message-filters [Not Installed]                 
79)      ros-kinetic-message-generation [Not Installed]              
80)      ros-kinetic-message-runtime [Not Installed]                 
81)      ros-kinetic-mk [Not Installed]                              
82)      ros-kinetic-nav-msgs [Not Installed]                        
83)      ros-kinetic-nodelet [Not Installed]                         
84)      ros-kinetic-nodelet-core [Not Installed]                    
85)      ros-kinetic-nodelet-topic-tools [Not Installed]             
86)      ros-kinetic-nodelet-tutorial-math [Not Installed]           
87)      ros-kinetic-octomap [Not Installed]                         
88)      ros-kinetic-opencv3 [Not Installed]                         
89)      ros-kinetic-orocos-kdl [Not Installed]                      
90)      ros-kinetic-pcl-conversions [Not Installed]                 
91)      ros-kinetic-pcl-msgs [Not Installed]                        
92)      ros-kinetic-pcl-ros [Not Installed]                         
93)      ros-kinetic-perception [Not Installed]                      
94)      ros-kinetic-perception-pcl [Not Installed]                  
95)      ros-kinetic-pluginlib [Not Installed]                       
96)      ros-kinetic-pluginlib-tutorials [Not Installed]             
97)      ros-kinetic-polled-camera [Not Installed]                   
98)      ros-kinetic-python-orocos-kdl [Not Installed]               
99)      ros-kinetic-qt-dotgraph [Not Installed]                     
100)     ros-kinetic-qt-gui [Not Installed]                          
101)     ros-kinetic-qt-gui-cpp [Not Installed]                      
102)     ros-kinetic-resource-retriever [Not Installed]              
103)     ros-kinetic-robot [Not Installed]                           
104)     ros-kinetic-robot-model [Not Installed]                     
105)     ros-kinetic-robot-state-publisher [Not Installed]           
106)     ros-kinetic-ros [Not Installed]                             
107)     ros-kinetic-ros-base [Not Installed]                        
108)     ros-kinetic-ros-comm [Not Installed]                        
109)     ros-kinetic-ros-core [Not Installed]                        
110)     ros-kinetic-ros-tutorials [Not Installed]                   
111)     ros-kinetic-rosbag [Not Installed]                          
112)     ros-kinetic-rosbag-storage [Not Installed]                  
113)     ros-kinetic-rosbash [Not Installed]                         
114)     ros-kinetic-rosbuild [Not Installed]                        
115)     ros-kinetic-rosconsole [Not Installed]                      
116)     ros-kinetic-rosconsole-bridge [Not Installed]               
117)     ros-kinetic-roscpp [Not Installed]                          
118)     ros-kinetic-roscpp-core [Not Installed]                     
119)     ros-kinetic-roscpp-serialization [Not Installed]            
120)     ros-kinetic-roscpp-traits [Not Installed]                   
121)     ros-kinetic-roscpp-tutorials [Not Installed]                
122)     ros-kinetic-rosgraph-msgs [Not Installed]                   
123)     ros-kinetic-roslang [Not Installed]                         
124)     ros-kinetic-roslaunch [Not Installed]                       
125)     ros-kinetic-roslib [Not Installed]                          
126)     ros-kinetic-roslisp [Not Installed]                         
127)     ros-kinetic-rosmake [Not Installed]                         
128)     ros-kinetic-rosmaster [Not Installed]                       
129)     ros-kinetic-rosmsg [Not Installed]                          
130)     ros-kinetic-rosnode [Not Installed]                         
131)     ros-kinetic-rosout [Not Installed]                          
132)     ros-kinetic-rospy [Not Installed]                           
133)     ros-kinetic-rospy-tutorials [Not Installed]                 
134)     ros-kinetic-rosservice [Not Installed]                      
135)     ros-kinetic-rostest [Not Installed]                         
136)     ros-kinetic-rostime [Not Installed]                         
137)     ros-kinetic-rostopic [Not Installed]                        
138)     ros-kinetic-rosunit [Not Installed]                         
139)     ros-kinetic-roswtf [Not Installed]                          
140)     ros-kinetic-rqt-action [Not Installed]                      
141)     ros-kinetic-rqt-bag [Not Installed]                         
142)     ros-kinetic-rqt-bag-plugins [Not Installed]                 
143)     ros-kinetic-rqt-common-plugins [Not Installed]              
144)     ros-kinetic-rqt-console [Not Installed]                     
145)     ros-kinetic-rqt-dep [Not Installed]                         
146)     ros-kinetic-rqt-graph [Not Installed]                       
147)     ros-kinetic-rqt-gui [Not Installed]                         
148)     ros-kinetic-rqt-gui-cpp [Not Installed]                     
149)     ros-kinetic-rqt-gui-py [Not Installed]                      
150)     ros-kinetic-rqt-image-view [Not Installed]                  
151)     ros-kinetic-rqt-launch [Not Installed]                      
152)     ros-kinetic-rqt-logger-level [Not Installed]                
153)     ros-kinetic-rqt-moveit [Not Installed]                      
154)     ros-kinetic-rqt-msg [Not Installed]                         
155)     ros-kinetic-rqt-nav-view [Not Installed]                    
156)     ros-kinetic-rqt-plot [Not Installed]                        
157)     ros-kinetic-rqt-pose-view [Not Installed]                   
158)     ros-kinetic-rqt-publisher [Not Installed]                   
159)     ros-kinetic-rqt-py-common [Not Installed]                   
160)     ros-kinetic-rqt-py-console [Not Installed]                  
161)     ros-kinetic-rqt-reconfigure [Not Installed]                 
162)     ros-kinetic-rqt-robot-dashboard [Not Installed]             
163)     ros-kinetic-rqt-robot-monitor [Not Installed]               
164)     ros-kinetic-rqt-robot-plugins [Not Installed]               
165)     ros-kinetic-rqt-robot-steering [Not Installed]              
166)     ros-kinetic-rqt-runtime-monitor [Not Installed]             
167)     ros-kinetic-rqt-rviz [Not Installed]                        
168)     ros-kinetic-rqt-service-caller [Not Installed]              
169)     ros-kinetic-rqt-shell [Not Installed]                       
170)     ros-kinetic-rqt-srv [Not Installed]                         
171)     ros-kinetic-rqt-tf-tree [Not Installed]                     
172)     ros-kinetic-rqt-top [Not Installed]                         
173)     ros-kinetic-rqt-topic [Not Installed]                       
174)     ros-kinetic-rqt-web [Not Installed]                         
175)     ros-kinetic-rviz [Not Installed]                            
176)     ros-kinetic-rviz-plugin-tutorials [Not Installed]           
177)     ros-kinetic-rviz-python-tutorial [Not Installed]            
178)     ros-kinetic-self-test [Not Installed]                       
179)     ros-kinetic-sensor-msgs [Not Installed]                     
180)     ros-kinetic-shape-msgs [Not Installed]                      
181)     ros-kinetic-simulators [Not Installed]                      
182)     ros-kinetic-smach-msgs [Not Installed]                      
183)     ros-kinetic-smach-ros [Not Installed]                       
184)     ros-kinetic-stage [Not Installed]                           
185)     ros-kinetic-stage-ros [Not Installed]                       
186)     ros-kinetic-std-msgs [Not Installed]                        
187)     ros-kinetic-std-srvs [Not Installed]                        
188)     ros-kinetic-stereo-image-proc [Not Installed]               
189)     ros-kinetic-stereo-msgs [Not Installed]                     
190)     ros-kinetic-tf [Not Installed]                              
191)     ros-kinetic-tf-conversions [Not Installed]                  
192)     ros-kinetic-tf2 [Not Installed]                             
193)     ros-kinetic-tf2-eigen [Not Installed]                       
194)     ros-kinetic-tf2-geometry-msgs [Not Installed]               
195)     ros-kinetic-tf2-kdl [Not Installed]                         
196)     ros-kinetic-tf2-msgs [Not Installed]                        
197)     ros-kinetic-tf2-py [Not Installed]                          
198)     ros-kinetic-tf2-ros [Not Installed]                         
199)     ros-kinetic-theora-image-transport [Not Installed]          
200)     ros-kinetic-topic-tools [Not Installed]                     
201)     ros-kinetic-trajectory-msgs [Not Installed]                 
202)     ros-kinetic-turtle-actionlib [Not Installed]                
203)     ros-kinetic-turtle-tf [Not Installed]                       
204)     ros-kinetic-turtle-tf2 [Not Installed]                      
205)     ros-kinetic-turtlesim [Not Installed]                       
206)     ros-kinetic-urdf [Not Installed]                            
207)     ros-kinetic-urdf-parser-plugin [Not Installed]              
208)     ros-kinetic-urdf-tutorial [Not Installed]                   
209)     ros-kinetic-vision-opencv [Not Installed]                   
210)     ros-kinetic-visualization-marker-tutorials [Not Installed]  
211)     ros-kinetic-visualization-msgs [Not Installed]              
212)     ros-kinetic-visualization-tutorials [Not Installed]         
213)     ros-kinetic-viz [Not Installed]                             
214)     ros-kinetic-webkit-dependency [Not Installed]               
215)     ros-kinetic-xacro [Not Installed]                           
216)     ros-kinetic-xmlrpcpp [Not Installed]                        
217)     tcl-vtk6 [Not Installed]                                    
218)     vtk6 [Not Installed]                                        



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y

No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 817 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

So I am clueless now, like I have no idea what's wrong or what doesn't work. In all honesty, on no OS I struggled to install something this hard. No offense, but this is just frustrating.

My sources list:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 66 Okt 11 14:03 cuda-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update-2.list

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   66 Okt 11 14:03 cuda-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update-2.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   64 Okt 11 14:03 cuda-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   64 Okt 11 14:03 cuda-9-0-local-cublas-performance-update.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   38 Okt 11 14:03 cuda-9-0-local.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   38 Okt 11 14:03 cuda-9-0-local.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Okt 11 11:55 docker.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Okt 11 11:55 docker.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Okt 11 14:03 google-chrome.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  189 Okt 11 14:03 google-chrome.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Okt 10 15:46 isv:ownCloud:desktop.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Okt 10 15:46 isv:ownCloud:desktop.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   49 Okt 11 14:03 matrix-riot-im.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   49 Okt 11 14:03 matrix-riot-im.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  459 Okt 11 14:03 mendeleydesktop.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  459 Okt 11 14:03 mendeleydesktop.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  146 Okt 11 14:03 mystic-mirage-ubuntu-pycharm-xenial.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  146 Okt 11 14:03 mystic-mirage-ubuntu-pycharm-xenial.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Okt 10 15:43 nvidia-docker.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Okt 10 15:43 nvidia-docker.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  130 Okt 11 14:03 peterlevi-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  130 Okt 11 14:03 peterlevi-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   51 Okt 11 14:03 ros-latest.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   51 Okt 11 14:03 ros-latest.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   56 Okt 11 14:03 skype-stable.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   56 Okt 11 14:03 skype-stable.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50 Okt 11 14:03 spotify.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   50 Okt 11 14:03 spotify.list.save
```

I had to remove universe one since it caused the priority (500 vs 1000) issue with the python-catkin-pkg. Apart from that all others are checked on the Ubuntu Software Center.

As for the cat /etc/apt/preferences.d, I have only one file called allow-downgrade with the following content:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=Ubuntu
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Any way of solving this?

Comment: "817 packages not upgraded" indicates a serious problem. Many possible causes. Most likely is a wrong-version package a few weeks or months ago. Wrong-version packages are one way to create "Impossible situations." If you cannot recall which package caused the problem, then you have three options: 1) Trace the dependencies using `apt-cache policy` until you find the problem, 2) Uninstall ALL non-Ubuntu software (including ROS) to restore your system to working condition, then reinstall them one-by-one, or 3) Live with it until your system breaks completely, then reinstall the entire OS.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04.
The fix for me was to slightly modify my `etc/apt/sources.list` file.

I uncommented the lines:

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial universe
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-updates universe
```

then `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full` worked just fine.